# Can i use text box names as values in a list?

Tags: c#, list, textbox

im creating a list to update a MySql db with values form text boxes, how can i make somthing like this work?

if i use the

```
    verdierX[0] = (int)decimal.Parse(box1.Text);
```

it works just fine 
but when i try to use it in a loop like this is blowes up. Anyone got a suggestion on how to solve this?

```
    int[] dbNavnX = new int[8]; 
    int[] verdierX = new int[8];
    string[] boxList = new string[8];

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        boxList[0] = "box1.Text";
        boxList[1] = "box2.Text";
        boxList[2] = "box3.Text";
        boxList[3] = "box4.Text";
        boxList[4] = "box5.Text";
        boxList[5] = "box6.Text";
        boxList[6] = "box7.Text";
        boxList[7] = "box8.Text";
    }

    private void sumX()
    {
        for (int sum = 0; sum < 8; sum++)
        {
            verdierX[sum] = (int)decimal.Parse(boxList[sum]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't quite understand what you are asking, could you clarify?

Comment: You are not assigning the contents of TextBoxes to boxList[] on Form1_Load. You are assigning "box1.Text" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, how about some Linq goodness:

```
var sumX = from Control control in Controls
            where 
                control.GetType() == typeof (TextBox) 
                && control.Name.StartsWith("box")
            select Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)control).Text);
```

Comment: works as long as you don't have any other TexBoxes whose name starts with "box"

Answer (score 2):

You should change your boxList array to hold references to the TextBoxes instead of strings:

```
TextBox[] boxList = new TextBox[8];
```

and

```
boxList[0] = box1;
boxList[1] = box2;
...
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Silly me, I thought he wanted to write less code... Btw, he'll need to rewrite the sumX() method, because that one expects strings with the textboxes' contents...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int[] verdierX = new int[8];

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)FindControl("box" + i.ToString());
        verdierX[i] = (int)decimal.Parse(tb.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah even better, will try this.

Comment: The name 'FindControl' does not exist in the current context.

what system namespace am i missing?

Comment: @Darkmage: Sorry, I thought you were doing ASP ;-) It's actually very similar (apart from the name Form1), and you didn't say.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using WPF, you can access the "me.controls" which is an array of all the controls available in your form. Watch out though, if your text box is on a panel or other container, you then use the object.controls to get the textbox.

Hope that works.